# Android - Implementation of Lazy loading of images with onScrollListener in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, lazy-loading

I have implemented lazy loading using onScrollListener stuff. One issue I am having is for the first time when activity is started the images don't display. Images get displayed when I scroll the listview. Any reason why the images don't load for the first time. Please let me know. Thanks.

The getView() code is as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ContentListHolder contentHolder = null;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            vi = inflater.inflate(layoutItem, null);

            contentHolder = new ContentListHolder();
            contentHolder.textview = (TextView)vi.findViewById(idText);
            contentHolder.imageView =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(idImage);

            vi.setTag(contentHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            contentHolder = (ContentListHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }        
        contentHolder.textview.setText("item "+position);
        contentHolder.imageView.setImageResource(layoutstub);
        Bitmap bitmap = imageLoader.getBitmapFromCache(data[position]);
        notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        if(bitmap != null)
        {           contentHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }       
        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: just post your adapter code, i mean getView() code.

Comment: You shouldn't use the notifyDataSetChanged() method in getView()

Comment: I removed notifyDataSetChanged(), but still having the same issue.

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `getView` does not make any sense at all... What did you want to achieve with that?

Answer (score 1):

It happens just because you haven't set the tag for your ImageView.

Try:

```
contentHolder.imageView.setTag(bitmap);
```

Comment: I tried this code in the getView() method, but it's not working.

Comment: @user1182217 let me know why are you taking bitmap from cache? Can't you take URL instead?

Comment: Please check this line... `Bitmap bitmap = imageLoader.getBitmapFromCache(data[position]);`. Here data represents the actual URL.

Comment: @user1182217 btw, what's there in getBitmapFromCache() logic?

Comment: This method will return the Bitmap from the cache which is a map. `private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));` The get method is as follows: `public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            return cache.get(id);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            return null;
        }
    }`